# Grep finding phone numbers in files

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How would I look for files in the `/etc` directory (but not subdirectories) that contain a standard United States long distance phone number, written using the pattern of `1-###-###-####`, where each `#` is replaced with a numeric digit.   Collect the filenames of every file in the `/etc` directory which contains such a pattern of numbers, and place them in the file `~/etcphone.txt`, one file name per line, sorted alphabetically, using absolute references.

This is what I have so far

```
egrep -l "1-[[:digit:]]{3}- " /etc/* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ egrep -l "\b1-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}\b" \
    /etc/* 2>/dev/null | sort > ~/etcphone.txt
```

The `\b` escape sequence matches a word boundary. This will prevent if from matching something like `1231-123-123-1234`.

Comment: Don't I have to sort it as well

Comment: Yes. I thought your question was just about the regular expression.

Comment: I've added the trivial sort and output redirection to the answer.

Comment: So I would write it 
down  
egrep -l "\b1-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}\b" /etc/* 2>/dev/null | sort >> ~/etcphone.txt

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking there. Other than using `>>` instead of `>` it looks the same as my answer. There's nothing in your question saying that the results should be appended instead of overwriting the file.

Comment: It says the output is wrong

Comment: Is it listing files it shouldn't, or not listing files it should? Could you provide details -- show the contents of a file that's incorrectly included or omitted from the results.

Comment: its showing content its not suppose to. the exact message is the output doesn't match.

Comment: I don't understand where that message is coming from. `egrep -l` doesn't print that. If a file doesn't match, it just leaves the filename out of the results, it doesn't print an error message. Is there more to your script, and the message comes from another part of it?

Comment: I will see if I cann copy the error message

Comment: Why do you have files with phone numbers in `/etc` in the first place? I checked a couple of my servers and they don't have any files like this.

Comment: Its a practice file that we are using. I have tried this command and it tells me the file exist but the output is incorrect. egrep -l "\b1-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}\b" /etc/* 2>/dev/null | sort > ~/etcphone.txt

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by _the file exists but the output is incorrect_. The only output should be a list of filenames. Please paste a transcript of your session into the question.

Answer (score 0):

`egrep -l "1(-[[:digit:]]{3}){3}[[:digit:]]" /etc/* 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

```
find /etc | xargs -I{} grep -l ‘1-[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}’ {} | sort -nr > ~/etcphone.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

```
cat filename.txt | grep '^[789][0-9]{9}'
```

This command is applicable only for 10 digit Indian mobile numbers starting with 7,8 or 9.

Comment: The OP asks to parse US phones numbers in multiple files in `/etc'.  How does this answer that question?